# React native expand and collapse a view width and height to full screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, height

I have created a react native expo app and I am currently using the react native calendars module. In my app, I have an agenda screen. In the screen, I have multiple different items that, when clicked I would like to animate them scaling to the full screen, similar to the google calendar app.

I have tried animating the height and width to the same height and width of the screen, but that just animates the item in the agenda list in place, so the width and height go off screen instead of animating to the full screen. I have also tried setting a position of absolute when animating, but that doesn't work either.

```
  expand = () => {
    const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.height, {
        toValue : height,
        duration : 600,
        easing : Easing.linear
      }).start(),
      Animated.timing(this.width, {
        toValue : width,
        duration : 600,
        easing : Easing.linear
      }).start()
    ])

  }
```

This code here controls the height and width expansion

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.item, {backgroundColor: this.props.item.type === 'HOMEWORK' ? this.props.item.color : '#fff', height : this.height, width : this.width, position: this.height > 67 ? 'absolute' : 'relative',}]}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.expand() } style = {{flex : 1, flexDirection : 'row'}}>


  </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>
```

[image: Agenda Screen results]
[image: Agenda Screen results 2]
Video animation:
https://i.imgur.com/Mw3m6vv.mp4

I expected that the view would take up the whole screen, but since it is nested within many items, it doesn't work like that. It just takes up the portion it is nested in. See below:

Comment: Are you solve it?